# EntityFramework update Entity with values of another?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a JSON string and I am deserlizing it into a EF entitiy.

```
Report result = js.Deserialize<Report>(json);
```

I am trying to update the entity in my context with the same ID to have the values of my deserlized one.

```
var reportToUpdate    _entities.Reports.Single(x => x.Id == result.Id)
```

I want to do something like this

```
reportToUpdate = set all values to the values from result
context.SaveChanges();
```

How can I do this?

I would like to avoid doing something like this:

```
report.param1 = result.param1
report.param3 = result.param3
report.param3 = result.param3
```

because there are about 50 properties on this entity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
context.Reports.Entry(reportToUpdate).CurrentValues.SetValues(result);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Be aware that SetValues does not follow navigational properties or related objects, only complex/simple properties of the entity itself.

Comment: With this method be sure to set the Key/Id of 'result' to that of 'reportToUpdate'. if 'result' has an Id=0 then it will throw an exception.

Comment: shouldn't that be context.Entry(reportToUpdate).CurrentValues.SetValues(result); That is contexts track the entry's, not the DBSets

Answer (score 1):

If you already populated the entity model, then you just need to do attach the entity

Try something like this.

```
_context.Reports.Attach(result);
_context.Entry(result).State= EntityState.Modified;
```

follow this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I tried this and I get an error that it already has one with the same ID. This 'new' one deserialized from json was an 'edit' to one already in the database.